# can not define int variable in enum - java

Tags: java, enums

i try to define enum with int in it, but i have error in eclipse : "Syntax error on token "int", delete this token"
my code:

```
 package util.enumurations;

public enum BooleanEnum
{  
  private int value;

  static
  {
    BooleanEnum[] arrayOfBooleanEnum = new BooleanEnum[2];
    arrayOfBooleanEnum[0] = False;
    arrayOfBooleanEnum[1] = True;
  }

  private BooleanEnum(int arg3)
  {
    int j;
    this.value = j;
  }

  public int getValue()
  {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing in an `enum` have to be the declaration of the possible values.

```
public enum BooleanEnum
{  
  False(0), True(1);    

  private final int value;

  static
  {
    BooleanEnum[] arrayOfBooleanEnum = new BooleanEnum[2];
    arrayOfBooleanEnum[0] = False;
    arrayOfBooleanEnum[1] = True;
  }

  private BooleanEnum(int arg3)
  {
    this.value = arg3;
  }

  public int getValue()
  {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless there is more to your enum, though, I'd just use java.lang.Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
java.lang.Boolean.TRUE, 
java.lang.Boolean.FALSE
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Actually The body of an enum type may contain `enum constants`. An enum constant defines an instance of the `enum` type.

What you are trying to is [You aren't gonna need it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it).

Just use a simple Boolean almost it self acts as ENUM for `true` `false` types.

[Use Boolean.valueOf();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28boolean%29)